# Tools for css troubleshooting

Tags: css, firebug

I use firebug and the web developer firefox addon for most css debugging. Both are excellent tools.  However, when there are bunch of style sheets and custom rules involved, I am unable to use either tool to see the sequence of rules application by which the final property value was derived.

Let me share an example to illustrate the difficulty I am facing within these tools. On one page of my site, the font-size of a particular section is larger than others.  Firebug shows me all the css rules that were applied to the element. It also shows me the rules that were discarded; these are shown with a strike-through.  This is great! But to find out the exact class rule responsible for the larger font size, I have to scroll through all the styles until I can spot a font-size rule that has not been struck through.  There does not seem to be a "search" function for the css panel (unlike the html panel).

How do you handle these situations?  Is there a better tool out there?  Or, is there some way to search for "font-size that has not been struck through" in the firebug css panel?  This may not be a huge issue for some but in my case I believe I can save lots of time if I can get past this issue.  Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tabrez

Comment: Wow, it sounds like you have *way too many* `font-size` styles overriding each other.

Comment: You should write your css in a way to avoid such issues. Never had to look up why something is "this way". Maybe read something about overriding css.

Comment: @PetrMarek - I have used the important! keyword in certain situations.  But I don't want that to be the norm.

Comment: @JustinSatyr - If you bring in UI controls from multiple frameworks, they come with their own style files too.  If I had more time on hand, I would do a clean merge of all stylesheet files.  But, I don't have that luxury.  Right now I am only worried  about the styles that may conflict or override the default site styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Firebug, view the drop-down options under the 'Style' tab in the firebug window.

There is an option to 'Only Show Applied Styles'.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to change browsers, Google Chrome's Inspect Element feature (right click > inspect element) will tell show you both all matched styles (overridden ones crossed through) as well as just the computed style. It gives you a link to the line in the css file.